# is there any other use of & other than bitwise AND

Tags: java, operators, bitwise-operators

I am going through SCJP 6 book by Kathy and Bret and came across some text from this book, chapter 4 (operators)

> Because you know by
>   now that Java is not C++, you won't be surprised that Java operators aren't typically
>   overloaded. There are, however, a few exceptional operators that come overloaded:

- The + operator can be used to add two numeric primitives together, or to
  perform a concatenation operation if either operand is a String.
- The &, |, and ^ operators can all be used in two different ways, although as
  of this version of the exam, their bit-twiddling capabilities won't be tested.

I am failing to understand the second use of &, | and ^ operators in java other than bitwise AND, OR and XOR respectively. What are the two different ways of using & operator in java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`&` can be applied on two `boolean` operands as a non short circuiting version of binary AND operator (unlike the short circuiting `&&` operator).

`|` can be applied on two `boolean` operands as a non short circuiting version of binary OR operator (unlike the short circuiting `||` operator).

`^` (XOR) can also be applied on two `boolean` operands.

To summarize, all 3 operators can serve as boolean operators (when applied to `boolean` operands) or bit-wise operators (when applies to integer operands).

These operators are described in [**JLS 15.22.2.**](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se10/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.22.2):

> **15.22.2. Boolean Logical Operators &, ^, and |**
>
> When both operands of a &, ^, or | operator are of type boolean or Boolean, then the type of the bitwise operator expression is boolean. In all cases, the operands are subject to unboxing conversion (§5.1.8) as necessary.
>
> - For &, the result value is true if both operand values are true; otherwise, the result is false.
> - For ^, the result value is true if the operand values are different; otherwise, the result is false.
> - For |, the result value is false if both operand values are false; otherwise, the result is true.

Comment: Little trick: `a^b` is the same as  `a!=b` with booleans

Comment: @MarkJeronimus yes, that's the behavior of boolean XOR.